# How to most efficiently restructure a character string for fasttime in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with characters in two columns like so:

```
01/01/2014 | 00:30
02/01/2014 | 01:00
03/01/2014 | 01:30 etc
```

The length of this data set varies but is easily over 300,000 rows each time the script is run. Eventually I know this script will need to deal with a data set of 30,000,000 rows plus.

I currently `paste` them in the following form:

```
DT[, DateTime := paste(Date, Time)
```

Which leads to:

```
01/01/2014 00:30
02/01/2014 01:00
03/01/2014 01:30 etc
```

I then use `as.POSIXct` to convert that into a POSIX date:

```
DT[, DateTime:= as.POSIXct(x = DateTime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")]
```

This works fine, converting the characters correctly, largely I believe because I set the format argument to match the structure of the character string it is fed.

However, I'd like to use the `fasttime` package, but there is an inherent problem in that it does not support a `format` argument to input. Therefore, when I run:

```
DT[, DateTime := fastPOSIXct(x = DateTime)]
```

`fasttime` has to interpret my data as the "order of interpretation is fixed: year, month, day, hour, minute, second." the output would come out like:

```
2006/07/07 00:30
2007/07/07 01:00
2008/07/07 01:30 etc
```

Therfore, it seems I either must use `as.POSIXct`, or find a way to manipulate the string into the right order.

What would be the most efficient way to allow me to use `fasttime`? How should I reorder the character string to match? Would you expect that it would be worth reordering the character strings in order to use `fasttime`, or would the added requirement to correct the strings make `fasttime` savings negligible?

Comment: Where did you get `fasttime` package from?

Comment: @DavidArenburg http://rforge.net/fasttime/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sub` to reorder your string first, and yes, I think that's going to be much faster than using base `as.POSIXct`:

```
DT[, DateTime := fastPOSIXct(sub('(\\d*)/(\\d*)/(\\d*) (.*)', '\\3-\\1-\\2 \\4', DateTime))]
```

You might also be able to speed this up more using `substr` instead of regular expressions, but it'll be much messier.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I've heard of these 'regex' things, but never used them. I may well have totally misunderstood how this works, but is the `x` at the end suppose to be what I'm operating on? i.e. DateTime

Comment: @DaveRGP yes, sorry, didn't read your variable names too carefully, fixed now

Comment: No Prob, I was wondering if you could expand your answer a little to explain exactly what that sub string is doing? I have no prior experience with regex, and am having trouble matching my reading to exactly what that part of the code is doing.

Comment: Also, I've noticed some (too me at least), weird behavior in fasttime and conversion. Have you got an answer to this? [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892116/does-fasttime-cache-values-outside-of-its-environment-if-so-why?lq=1)

Comment: Don't worry about the above link. It was a silly mistake on my part.

Comment: @DaveRGP you can find online tools that visualize the regular expressions - [here's one](http://regexper.com/#(%5Cd*)%5C%2F(%5Cd*)%5C%2F(%5Cd*)%20(.*)) (note I had to modify the special symbols a little to fit javascript's slightly different syntax)