# Does fasttime cache values outside of it's environment? If so, why?

Tags: r, data.table, posixct

DISCLAIMER: I assume 'cache' and 'environment' are the right words here, though I am new to programming, so I may have misunderstood the terminology.

I have recently been trying to get to grips with the package fasttime for R, and I realise know there it has a behavior that I've not seem in documentation and also has been the root of my problems getting it to function.

TL;DR - If I use fast time to convert to POSIXct from a parent object into child one, then use it in a different way to calculate from the intact parent to child 2, child two will always have the result of child two, even if they should be different when calculated entirely independently.

Long version -

I have a long list of dates and times as characters to convert into POSIX (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827948/how-to-most-efficiently-restructure-a-character-string-for-fasttime-in-data-tabl))

And example data set and working file can be [found here](https://github.com/DaveRGP/fasttimeError).

When I read the example file I need to build a single DateTime column, then convert it to POSIXct.

First I read:

```
setwd("~/GitHub/fasttimeError")

example <- fread("datesAndTimes.csv")
# read example file of dates and times
```

Then I paste:

```
example[ , DateTime := paste(ConsumptionDate, variable)]
# paste dates with times to make DateTime single column for POSIX conversion
```

Then I attempt to convert:

```
library(fasttime)
# load library for fastPOSIXct

test1 <- example[ , DateTime := fastPOSIXct(x = DateTime)]
# this will read the data as starting in 2006

test2 <- example[ , DateTime := fastPOSIXct(sub('(\\d*)/(\\d*)/(\\d*) (.*)', '\\3-\\1-\\2 \\4', DateTime))]
# this should produce an identical file to test 1
```

Darn, neither process worked correctly. They both produce a data set starting at 2006.

But for some reason, if I clear the whole working environment (in RStudio), and re run the exact same code but SKIP the line that creates `test1`, then my object labelled `test2` converts perfectly.

Why?

Comment: Do you you realise that `:=` modifies in place? Did you try your code not within `data.table` environment?

Comment: i.e., do `test1 <- copy(example); test1[ , DateTime := fastPOSIXct(x = DateTime)]` and similar for `test2`.

Comment: I do, however I also thought that as I was assigning to a new object, the copy took place first, then the assignment? From what I've seen of data.table posts around the place a lot of the corrections people suggest are just for this reason, so that the file isn't copied over. Is this wrong?

Comment: You should study data.table's documentation and vignettes.

Comment: I see. If you put it the form of answer I will close the question. thank you.