# How to most efficiently convert a character string of "01 Jan 2014" to POSIXct i.e. "2014-01-01" yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: regex, r, date, posixct

I already have a partial answer to the problem here, which I understand as far as it is explained: [How to most efficiently restructure a character string for fasttime in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827948/how-to-most-efficiently-restructure-a-character-string-for-fasttime-in-data-tabl)

However, the task has been extended, and needs to deal with a variation of the orginal formatting.

I have a large dataset, with a column of dates of character class in the form of:

```
01 Jan 2014
```

or:

```
dd MMM yyyy
```

Which I want to restructure to feed into `fastPOSIXct` which only accepts character input in `POSIXct` order:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

The above linked question notes that an efficient approach would be to use regex and then supply the output to `fast.time`. Here do I need to extend this to include a method to understand monthly abbreviations, convert to numeric, then rearrange? How would I do this? I know that there is a `month.abb` as a built in constant. Should I be using this, or is there a smarter way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638545/speedup-conversion-of-2-million-rows-of-date-strings-to-posix-ct; Also, in there, try package `fasttime`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using `lubridate`:

```
x <- "01 Jan 2014"
x
[1] "01 Jan 2014"
library(lubridate)
dmy(x)
[1] "2014-01-01 UTC"
```

Of course `lubridate` functions accept `tz` argument too. To see a complete list of acceptable arguments see `OlsonNames()`

#### Benchmark

I decided to update this answer with some empirical data using the `micro benchmark` package and the `lubridate` option for use fasstime.

```
library(micro benchmark)
microbenchmark(dmy(x), times = 10000)
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min      lq     mean   median      uq     max neval
 dmy(x) 1.992639 2.02567 2.142212 2.041514 2.07153 39.1384 10000

options(lubridate.fasttime = T)

microbenchmark(dmy(x), times = 10000)
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 dmy(x) 1.993326 2.02488 2.136748 2.039467 2.065326 163.2008 10000
```

Comment: Is it the case that the fastime option only works with posix strings? Hence the observed times?